# Regarding tikzpicture, 1) ordering, 2) box

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I loaded an example data from .tikz file.

The file was exported from MATLAB using `matlab2tikz` function.

In the file, there are three plots with the order what I set.

When I imported the file in TexStudio and plotted them, it was not the same order with MATLAB.

When I have changed the order of `\addplot` back and forth, it changes if there is no marker.

But if there is a marker, then it appears on the top even its `\addplot` is on the bottom of the order. (You can see the differences from the below figures)

And sometimes, I have 2 Y axis at the same time I want to have a box which is `box('on')` function in the MATLAB.

What I want to do is

1) Find a way to change the order of plots from `\addplot` syntax when they have markers.

2) Have a box even when `\begin{axis}` contains `axis y line*=left`.
(The below has no solid line on its right side.)

[image]
[image]

Let me attach the code what I used in .tikz file.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[width=5cm, height=3cm, at={(0.307in,0.179in)},
             scale only axis, xmin=0, xmax=10, ymin=0, ymax=20,
             grid=both,axis y line*=left]
\addplot [color=red, line width=1.0pt]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   11.281\\
1   12.173\\
2   13.379\\
3   17.849\\
4   16.629\\
5   10.586\\
6   17.863\\
7   12.878\\
8   16.176\\
9   18.569\\
10  13.865\\
};
\addplot [color=white!60!black, line width=1.0pt, mark size=0.7pt, 
          mark=triangle, mark options={solid, white!60!black}]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   14.692\\
1   12.988\\
2   13.286\\
3   18.048\\
4   13.686\\
5   5.874\\
6   11.792\\
7   14.119\\
8   12.448\\
9   16.188\\
10  8.179\\
};
\addplot [color=black, line width=1.0pt]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
0   17.624\\
1   1.057\\
2   16.775\\
3   12.581\\
4   13.404\\
5   14.429\\
6   14.062\\
7   17.105\\
8   13.163\\
9   12.295\\
10  9.593\\
};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `plotcyclelist` can be used to control the formatting of each plot. Several are built into `pgfplots` such as `color`, `exotic` and `black white`, or you can make your own with `\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist {cycle list name}{cycle list}`, where cycle list nominates line and marker colors, shapes etc. See section 4.7.7 of the manual for details.

To get a solid second y-axis, change `axis y line*=left` to `axis lines=box`.

I added `line join=bevel,` which improves how lines are joined at the coordinates.

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=1.15,
}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{set1}{%   <--
    {color=red,mark=square*}, 
    {color=white!60!black,mark=triangle*}, 
    {color=black,mark=diamond*},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[width=5cm, height=3cm, at={(0.307in,0.179in)},
    scale only axis, xmin=0, xmax=10, ymin=0, ymax=20,
    grid=both,
    every axis plot/.append style={line width=1pt},
    mark size=0.7pt,
    mark options={solid},
    line join=bevel,     %<--
    axis lines=box,      %<--
    cycle list name=set1 %<--
       ]
    \addplot
    table[row sep=crcr]{%
        0   11.281\\
        1   12.173\\
        2   13.379\\
        3   17.849\\
        4   16.629\\
        5   10.586\\
        6   17.863\\
        7   12.878\\
        8   16.176\\
        9   18.569\\
        10  13.865\\
    };
    \addplot
    table[row sep=crcr]{%
        0   14.692\\
        1   12.988\\
        2   13.286\\
        3   18.048\\
        4   13.686\\
        5   5.874\\
        6   11.792\\
        7   14.119\\
        8   12.448\\
        9   16.188\\
        10  8.179\\
    };
    \addplot
    table[row sep=crcr]{%
        0   17.624\\
        1   1.057\\
        2   16.775\\
        3   12.581\\
        4   13.404\\
        5   14.429\\
        6   14.062\\
        7   17.105\\
        8   13.163\\
        9   12.295\\
        10  9.593\\
    };
    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll have a look the manual. :) And I learnt many from your code! But still.. I think I have to find a solution about the overlap between different lines when their values are close to. :) Have a good day!